# What are the default forecolor and backcolor of a disabled control?

Tags: c#, colors, controls

I checked a lot of sites in Google and I found a great number of explanations how to change the colours of a disabled control.
I was unable however to find what the standard colours of a disabled control are. I know the standard colours for enabled controls:

```
Color controlEnabledBackColor = SystemColors.Control; // ARGB=(255, 240, 240, 240)
Color controlEnabledForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText; // ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 0)
```

What I am trying to find out is:

```
 Color controlDisabledBackColor = SystemColors.???; // ARGB=(?, ?, ?, ?)
 Color controlDisabledForeColor = SystemColors.???; // ARGB=(?, ?, ?, ?)
```

the colours themselves for the disabled controls and not only their names. Please advise how I can find out in C# or where the colours for the disabled control are specified.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on the user theme, but it's not really something you should mess with; users set the colors they do for particular reasons pertaining to their preferences or visual ability and you should leave them to their choices

Comment: @
Caius Jard Thank you for your input. I am asking not in order to "mess with". I want to know the names and the ARGBs for disabled (ghosted) controls.